# Monit wait for a file to start a process?

Tags: monit

Basically the monit to start a process "CAD" when a file "product_id" is ready. My config is as below:

```
check file product_id with path /etc/platform/product_id
  if does not exist then alert

check process cad with pidfile /var/run/cad.pid   
  depends on product_id   
  start = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/root/cad/scripts;./run-cad.sh 2>&1 | logger -t CAD'" with timeout 120 seconds   
  stop = "/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/root/cad/scripts;./stop-cad.sh 2>&1 | logger -t CAD'"
```

I’m expecting “monit” to call “start” until the file is available. But it seems it restarted the process (stop and start) every cycle.

Is there anything configured wrong here?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: why do you use a "check process" block? Looking at the documentation it seems like you can execute a script if a file doesn't exist in a "check file" block
https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#EXISTENCE-TESTING

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's restarting every cycle is because the `product_id` file is not ready. Anything that depends on `product_id` will be restarted if the check fails.

I would suggest writing a script that checks for the existence of `product_id` and starts CAD if it's there. You could then run this script from a "check program" block in monit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
check program ThisIsMyProgram with path "/home/user/program_check.sh"
        every 30 cycles
        if status == 1 then alert
```

This will run the shell script, and error if status = 1.

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/path/to/file/that/needs/to/exist.json
PID=$(sudo pidof ThisIsMyProgram)

if [ -s $FILE ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$PID" ];then
        exit 0
    else
        sudo service thisismyprogram start 2>&1 >> /dev/null
        exit 1
    fi
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Shell script checks if file exist, if it does it will start process and keep it running.